# Ionic side menu is rendring without border in iOS 8

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building an app using Ionic framework and Apache Cordova, when I test my app in android the UI is perfectly rendered, but when I test it in iOS 8 using the browser (Google chrome or Safari) the side menu is borderless, the menu I am talking about is this [one](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/), any help or suggestion is very appreciated.

There is also couple of other rendering bugs here and there and I am looking to use another framework, Framework7 seems interesting, any thoughts or feedback on it is welcome.

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Comment: Still the same! I switched to Framework7!

Comment: If it supported anything other than iOS I would be all over it. Native iOS is my strongpoint but any solution that bridges the gaps between iOS / Android / WP I am all for. This is where ionic / Cordova was supposed to shine. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, they are pushing the product really well, with all he feature they are adding but they have to fix these kinda of bugs if they want people to use their solution, for me FW7 is all I need and it is not that difficult to learn either! So I went with it!